# How to store ffmpeg output direct to s3 bucket using python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I had implemented the FFmpeg function to convert video format using python but I need to save its output directly to the s3 bucket from where it takes as input but I don't have any idea about it. Below is my code for converting video format

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3',
            region_name = S3_REGION,
            aws_access_key_id = S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
            aws_secret_access_key = S3_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY)
    os.popen("ffmpeg -i '{input}' -ac 2 -b:v 2000k -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -b:a 160k -vprofile high -bf 0 -strict experimental -f mp4 '{output}.mp4'".format(input = avi_file_path, output = output_name))
```

Can anyone suggest me how can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You could pipe the the output of ffmpeg to AWS Cli copy command. Something like this (not tested):

```
ffmpeg -i '{input}' -ac 2 -b:v 2000k -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -b:a 160k -vprofile high -bf 0 -strict experimental -f mp4 pipe:1 | aws s3 cp - s3://test-bucket/youroutput.mp4
```

EDIT

Due to the nature of the mp4 this won't work, mp4 need to be seekable and a stream is not seekable. One way could be to add `-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov` to the command, this will create a fragmented mp4, which is a kind of different format with limited (with respect to the normal mp4) playback capability.
Alternatively I suggest if you can to create the file locally and later upload to S3.

Comment: It's not working I had tried but it throwing error like this [mp4 @ 0x55a76f02dc80] muxer does not support non seekable output
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -"

Comment: You are right and that's depend on the nature of the mp4 format. I edited my answer.